# How to make this query faster... a lot of inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query takes 11 seconds to complete. I've tried removing a few fields to make it go faster without luck.
Is there a way to optimize this?

```
select 
    max(ig.group_name) as item_code, 
    MAX(ig.description) as item_desc, 
    (SUM(oi.qty * ip1.amount) / MAX(ig.amount)) as qtySum, 
    MAX(ig.unit) as unit, MAX(ip1.cat) as cat, 
    max(i.ItemRoute) as ItemRoute 
from 
    order_items oi
    inner join orders o on o.localID = oi.local_order_id 
    inner join items_pc ip1  on (ip1.item = oi.item_code and ip1.unit = oi.unit) 
    inner join item_groups ig on ig.id = ip1.ItemGroup 
    inner join items i on i.item = ip1.item 
    inner join customers c on o.customer_id = c.id 
where 
    oi.qty > 0  and 
    o.status = 'submitted' and 
    i.ItemGroup is not null and 
    o.delivery_date between '7/27/2014' and '7/30/2014'  
group by ip1.ItemGroup 
order by ItemRoute, cat, item_code
```

Comment: How often the data is updated? Is it possible to cache results? Which date intervals usually passed as parameters and which intervals are stored in the `Orders`? What is selectivity percentage of typical query for every table?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You don't select ItemGroup so the result must be very confusing !?!?!

Comment: oh, and I'm MySQL. I have no idea what a '7/27/2014' is - so I've no way of telling if something is bigger or smaller than it!

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to say without having your real data, but the workflow to optimize is roughly

- Look at your execution plan
- Add/remove indexes or other optimizations
- Repeat until you have desired performance

As a general rule, try to reduce the number of rows to scan as early as possible in your queries.

Reducing early is a bit hard to explain, but if you have three tables, A, B and C with each 1M rows. If you have a where condition that gives 100k rows on A, 100k rows on B and 1k rows on C, if you experience that A is joined with B before the result of that is joined with C you will probably look up something like 100k rows, but if you get C joined with A first before the result is joined with B you will probably look up something like 1k rows.

Likewise when you have a table with columns A and B, and your where clause includes both A and B. If the filter on A returns 100k rows and the filter on B returns 1k rows you want an index(B, A), not index(A, B) to reduce the search space as quickly as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "as early as possible"? Is there a way to reduce the rows before the final where statement?

Comment: +1 from side .. @boruchsiper yes this is the perfect answer in case of joins. Execution plan works like a charm if we use it in a perfect way

Comment: @boruchsiper I updated the answer with an explanation of what reducing early might look like.

Comment: All good stuff. But a bit premature. There are more basic problems here.